# How to generate an array of objects, having an array with keys and having another array with objects?

Tags: javascript

The first array is the one containing the keys, the second is the array of objects.

[image]

Then it should generate an array of the objects that contain those keys.
Then it should generate an array of the objects that contain those keys, that is, the keys of the first array.

I'm trying

```
this.fields.filter((index) => {
  const newValue = this.data.filter((data, indexData)=>{
     index = indexData;
   });
 });
```

`this.fields` contains the keys and `this.data` contains the array of objects in which I want to extract them according to the key.

Comment: How do the objects _"contain_" those keys? Please provide actual examples of the initial data and what you want the result to look like

Comment: Filter is the wrong function for this, you want `map()`

Comment: The callback function for `filter()` has to return a truthy value that says whether to keep that array element in the result.

Comment: Show examples of the two arrays and what the desired result is, because you haven't described it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Set() and .has to check if one of the keys is a a key in fields.

```
const fields = new Set(this.fields)
const newValue = this.data.filter(data =>
     Object.keys(data).some(key=>fields.has(key)))
```